# Getting a macro to concat AND stringify

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

The approach to concatenate in **C**/C++ in a preprocessor macro is to use ##.
The approach to stringify is to use #.
I'm trying to concat AND stringify. This is generating a warning from g++ (3.3.2)

```
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE2(x, y) TOKENPASTE(x, y)      // concat
#define TOKENPASTE3(x, y) TOKENPASTE(#x, #y)    // concat-stringify (warnings)
const char* s = TOKENPASTE3(Hi, There)
```

It is not acceptable to get the warning

> "test_utils/test_registration.h:34:38: warning: pasting ""Hi"" and
>   ""There"" does not give a valid preprocessing token"

although (using the -E option) I see that it generates:

```
const char* s = "Hi""There";
```

Which looks right to me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a version of GCC that's over a decade old?

Comment: It is actually a safety-critical fork from a decade ago. It is from WindRiver 653. That's out of my hands.

Comment: Well, you already have two strings, after `#x` and `#y`; you don't need to concat them into a single token, just use `#x #y`.

Comment: That concat is unnecessary. `"Hi" "There"` will be interpreted as `"HiThere"` even without doing so.

Comment: The preprocessor simply doesn't allow concatenation of strings using the concatenation operator. From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace): "Only tokens that form a valid token together may be pasted". String-literal concatenation is handled by another [compiler phase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The preprocessor already concatenates adjacent string literals. So your macro is unnecessary. Example:

```
#define TOKENPASTE3(x, y) #x #y
const char* s = TOKENPASTE3(Hi, There);
```

becomes `"Hi" "There"`. However, if you wanted to stick with your approach, you need to use an extra level of indirection to macro expand your new token:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) STRINGIFY(x ## y)
```

becomes `"HiThere"`.